# Faint line visible on non-retina screens

Tags: css, retina-display

I'm not even sure this is in the correct category but I'll ask and perhaps someone will guide me if not.

See the attached image. This is a tabbed navigation structure built with an unordered list and a single div to conceal the bottom border of the active tab. There is faint bottom border visible on the active tab only on non-retina screens. It can be any non-retina screen (not just mine). I can even see it when viewed at BrowserStack on a non-retina screen.

The container for the structure has a bottom border of 1px solid #ccc and the active tab uses an absolutely positioned div of 4px solid #fff to cover the line at the bottom of the active tab. This works perfectly with the exception of the faint line on non-retina screens.

I've Googled and searched StackOverflow with no luck. Any thoughts, ideas or suggestions would be appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a `button` or an `input`?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @nashcheez, it's neither. It's a tab navigation structure made up of an unordered list and a div to cover the bottom border of the active tab.

Comment: @VilleKoo, I could but would rather not. A lot of the code is proprietary and uses handlebars, data files, JS, markup and CSS. I was really more interested in whether anyone had seen this behavior before. I'm not convinced it's a code issue per say.

If not showing the code prevents an answer to the question, I'll understand. Thanks!

Comment: I would presume the `div` to cover the `border-bottom` of the unordered list is positioned absolutely. Maybe the `top` or `bottom` attributes do not have the appropriate values, or maybe an immediate parent has not been provided a `position: relative`?

Comment: Thanks @nashcheez - you are correct, absolutely positioned div to cover the bottom border. The parent has position relative. I'm attaching another image showing the inspector view of the tab with the bottom border covered.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding backface-visibility: hidden; to the bottom border. Thanks for the feedback!